C++ - undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
I installed Visual Studio Code, and I'm trying to set up SFML. This is the link to the YouTube video I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZE700aaT5I (timestamp: 05:17)
The following code block is what I have in my main.cpp so far. I got this code from the SFML website. Here's the link for your reference: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/start-linux.php
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

Here's what I typed in the terminal so far. Please remember that I replaced <(sfml-install-path)> with the correct path.

g++ -c main.cpp -I<(sfml-install-path)>/include (this made a main.o)

g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L<(sfml-install-path)>/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system


After I press Enter after 2, I get a message saying:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

YouTube and StackOverflow offered a few reasons/solutions:

I don't have a main(), so create a main().
-> I have a main(), so I don't think this is the issue.

I didn't save before running.
-> I initially did not save before running and thought this was the problem. However, I Ctrl+S and ran it, and I'm still getting this issue. I also went to Settings, and searched up 'Code runner' and 'Save all" to see if the Code-runner:Save All Files Before Run was checked off, and I don't even see that on my screen.

Add -mwindows at the end (so I would type g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L<sfml-install-path>/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -mwindows)
-> This also did not work, and I'm running into the same issue.

Double-check the path.
-> I did, and it's the correct path.


What am I missing out on? Also, I'm new to VS Code and SFML, so please be patient with me.

Side note : if you want to develop code for Windows. Forget about visual studio code for now... just use "Visual studio community edition" (and vcpkg) it will be much easier to get into.

I already use Visual Studio Community Edition, but I was trying to get into VS Code and SFML because I want to develop a game.

Did you install SFML using pacman? The official VSCode documentation tells you to use msys2 to install MinGW. With msys2 you have package management through pacman. SFML is one of the packages and they all install to the system location so you need not set the include directory or link folder. You will have to link to the sfml libraries however.

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0 You definitely didn't follow the official VSCode instructions for MinGW: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

I also went to Settings, and searched up 'Code runner This is also wrong / not the path for success. Once you have external libraries code-runner will get in your way because the code-runner configuration is global against all of your code.. You need to either switch to use the official tasks.json method or use CMake and the CMakeTools extension or use a MakeFile and the Makefile tools extension.

What am I missing out on? On top of all the other issues I pointed out, my guess about the linker error is you installed SFML libraries that are incompatible with your compiler.

I did. I also checked the MinGW installation using the command prompts listed in the link you provided. I also followed this tutorial for help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMWD7wfhgNY.

I am not sure if this is an appropriate question, but can I ask if you have C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin as one of your user environment paths? I have that, and in my system variables path, I have C:\MinGW\bin. I'm not sure if this is correct. Edit: Also, I know it says to please avoid extended discussions in comments, but it won't let me move this discussion to chat.

Once you add -mwindows, you must define WinMain() instead of main().

I didn't see that when I looked at this earlier. If you leave off the -mwindows MinGW will look for int main() and if it doesn't find int main it looks for WinMain.

I'm reopening this question. Undefined reference to WinMain (C++ MinGW) was completely irrelevant and should never be mentioned here, and in undefined reference to WinMain@16 none of the answers is relevant to this question - they are all saying "you don't have int main() function" and one is about SDL library.

@Yksisarvinen, You read the second one improperly. you are probably missing a main. And you probably have no (proper) WinMain either! and Make sure you have main() or WinMain() defined and g++ should do the right thing.

@3CxEZiVlQ OP has int main() function, it's clearly there in the question. Unless you can prove that it's not there when OP is compiling their program, it is not relevant.

@StephenNewell Please explain why do you think that does answer this question.

The linked page explains why gcc wants WinMain if main is provided.

@3CxEZiVlQ The conclusion of this answer is this: "But as you can see above, g++ has no problem with standard main even for a GUI subsystem program.". I don't see a single place where it would claim that g++ would want both main and WinMain in a program. Unless you show that -mwindows or -Wl,-subsystem,windows is inferred from g++ main.o -o sfml-app -L<(sfml-install-path)>/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system somehow, then it does not answer this question.

@abc - I'm sorry for your first experience with StackOverflow. You wrote a fine question, with [mcve] and doing good research first. Posting another question for the same issue isn't really okay, but as you explained - it was a different enough question to at least reject "you got wrong versions of SFML" hypothesis from here, so I think it's passable. In return, you got tons of incoherent and conflicting advice, most of which isn't even relevant. I can only say that while mistakes are made sometimes, it's rarely this bad and I hope you won't judge the whole site by this experience.

@Yksisarvinen Thank you for your comment. I truly don't know why my question got closed again. I tried everything that people mentioned here and on other similar posts, and I'm still running into the same issue. I don't know what to do at this point, but maybe I can uninstall and reinstall VS Code and SFML. Can you suggest any tutorials/articles regarding setting up SFML with VS Code?

I am sorry if I led you astray. I felt bad that we were giving so much advice in which at least some of it was conflicting. My advice is to remove your old version of mingw and use the recommended msys2 + pacman to install the ucrt version of SFML. Then install the CMake tools extension of vscode and use a CMakeLists.txt for your SFML. This will require you to learn some things but it will help you get a working system. With a CMakeLists.txt you should be able to build your executable inside or outside of VSCode or even transition to a different IDE in the future.

One thing I caution you is msvc and MinGW are not usually compatible with each other for c++ based code. You need MinGW binaries for MinGW and msvc binaries for msvc.

If you're compiling for the Windows subsystem, the entry point is expected to be as such:
int __clrcall WinMain(
  [in]           HINSTANCE hInstance,
  [in, optional] HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  [in]           LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  [in]           int       nShowCmd
);

For the console subsystem, the entry point is expected to be as such:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

Both, of course, use C linking, so you can get away with simplified (but definitely wrong) definitions if you prefer.

I am aware that it's technically "linking", not "compiling".

So, I replaced int main() with what you suggested. So now I have int __clrcall WinMain(
[in]           HINSTANCE hInstance,
[in, optional] HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
[in]           LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
[in]           int       nShowCmd
){...return 0;}. This outputs an error and tells me that __clrcall is valid only in C++/CLI mode. Did I set up VS Code wrong?

Use __stdcall instead

Yes, I tried, and it's showing me the errors: identifier "HINSTANCE" is undefined, identifier "LPSTR" is undefined.

@abc You need #include <windows.h>

@RemyLebeau Yes, I also tried that, and it's still outputting the same error.

@abc HINSTANCE and LPSTR should not be undefined if you use windows.h. If they are then your setup is really messed up.

@Blindy I don't see anything mentioning 'subsystem' in the question, I believe you should elaborate why is this relevant to your answer. And what do you mean by simplified (but definitely wrong) definitions?

@3CxEZiVlQ I see it. It's in the section "I searched the internet, found this answer, tried it, didn't help". It's not part of the core issue.

@Yksisarvinen the subsystem windows is default, and -mwindows is not a solution and the solution is in the dupe that you have removed: /entry:mainCRTStartup

@3CxEZiVlQ That's MSVC flag for heaven's sake! OP is not trying to compile with MSVC!

@Yksisarvinen it doesn't matter what you compile (again, actually link) with, the subsystem is a flag of the Windows .exe file format. Please don't pollute this thread with your confusion.
